# Flask server returning 400 error code from JS rest call

Tags: javascript, rest, flask

I'm calling my Flask view function (API) via Javascript (FETCH).

I'm having success with the GET method, but when using the PATCH method I'm receiving a 400 error code
(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)).

I reviewed the url, seems ok and the ID is being passed as an integer, so no clue on why it's giving this error message.

This function (load_follow_link) is fetching via GET and updating my "Follow" to "Unfollow" tag (no errors here):

```
function load_follow_link(id) {
    apply_csrf_token();

    fetch(`/follow_unfollow/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.is_following)
            document.getElementById('follow-unfollow-btn').innerHTML = 'Unfollow';
        else 
            document.getElementById('follow-unfollow-btn').innerHTML = 'Follow';
        
        document.getElementById('followers-count').innerHTML = data.followers_count;
        document.getElementById('following-count').innerHTML = data.following_count;
    });
}
```

This is the PATCH function (follow_unfollow) triggering the error message. It is supposed to call the view function and update the DB:

```
function follow_unfollow(id) {
    apply_csrf_token();
    
    fetch(`/follow_unfollow/${id}`, {
        method: 'PATCH'
    })
    .then(() => {
        load_follow_link(id);
    });
}
```

view function (doesn't get executed when request method is PATCH)

```
@app.route('/follow_unfollow/<int:tutor_id>', methods=['GET','PATCH'])
@login_required
def follow_unfollow(tutor_id):
    """ GET: returns if user is following the tutor, followers and following total
        PUT: follow or unfollow
    """
    user = Users.query.get(current_user.id)
    try:
        tutor = Tutors.query.get(tutor_id)
    except NoResultFound:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Tutor not registered"}, status=401)

    following_count = user.following_total()
    followers_count = tutor.followers_total()
    is_following = user.is_following(tutor)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify(is_following=is_following, followers_count=followers_count,
            following_count=following_count)
    
    elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        if is_following:
            user.unfollow(tutor)
        else:
            user.follow(tutor)
        db.session.commit()
        return success.return_response(message='Successfully Completed', status=204)
    else:
        return jsonify(error="GET or PUT request required", status=400)
```

I appreciate the help

Comment: Test for `print(request.method)` inside the functions to make sure you have `PATCH`

Answer (score 0):

Could be you are not returning a valid response. Where is `success` defined in `success.return_response`?

Why not just `return jsonify(...)`?

Comment: It doesn't enter the view function at all, it just sends back the request